# Kinect on TurtleBot

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm going to get a one turtlebot 3 model, but I don't know does it work with Kinect ? If you have knowledge about it please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269348/kinect-on-turtlebot/) by [mayice](https://answers.ros.org/users/31661/mayice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly modify your TurtleBot3 to work with a Kinect. However it's not a standard supported configuration which can be expected to work out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0